# Trigger an applet button from javascript

Tags: java, javascript, applet

i want to trigger an applet button on click of a normal html button using javascript

```
public class appletToWrite extends Applet{
Button write;
static String msPath;
static String msData;
public appletToWrite()
{
    this.write = new Button("Save");
}

public static void initializeData(String asPath, String asData){
    msPath = asPath;
    msData = asData;
}

public void init() { 
    add(this.write, "Center");
    this.write.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent paramActionEvent) {
            foo();
        }
    }); }


public void foo(){
    new appletToWrite.WriteText();
}

public class WriteText {
    WriteText() {
        try {
            String str2 = "D:\\Documents and Settings\\varun.aggarwal\\Desktop\\sample\\wow.htm";
            File localFile = new File(str2);
            localFile.createNewFile();
            BufferedWriter localBufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(localFile, true));
            String str1="helllllllo";
            localBufferedWriter.write(str1);
            localBufferedWriter.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File Successfully Saved!!! ");

        }
        catch (Exception localException) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, localException.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

}

is it possible???

this is something related to permissions as i found that file IO permissions are availabale only when i click on applet button and not when i click html button and call the applet method foo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, both JavaScript to Applet and Applet to Javascript.

Take a look at this page for code samples: [Java - Javascript interaction](http://www.raditha.com/java/javascript.php).

Comment: basically i want to call the actionlistner of button included in applet

Comment: Just create some public method that JS can call, and make this method called by the button's action listener. Calling the method from JS will then give you the same behavior as clicking the button. http://www.raditha.com/java/alert.php

Comment: I do not understand your last comment.  Did you mean that the *example shown at* http://www.raditha.com/java/alert.php does not work in your browser/JRE?  If the answer is 'yes', what is the make and version of the browser, and supplier/version of Java?  (It works here in a latish version of FF running Java 1.6.0_23 from Sun on Win 7.)

Comment: i meant i tried the same thing but its not working for me,the example is working fine... basically i want to trigger the action listner of an applet buttong from javascript

Comment: Then it means that you are missing something, as the example is OK and your code is not. Review all the example, create your code carefully, test on similar/equal environments (this is very important) first, but before that take a break. Too much time on a single issue makes you miss obvious mistakes, right in front of you all the time =)

Comment: @ mdrg - the last line is really necessary for all developers and is very true... but the thing is i have 2 buttons on page i want on click of HTML button my applet button gets called

Answer (score 1):

create a method in applet wrap all code in that method and call that method foo() from action listener.

like

```
actionPerformed(){
        foo();
    }//just illustration
```

now

```
<applet code="com.yourcompany.MyApplet"
mayscript="true" name="myApplet" width="200" height="100">
```

and myApplet will have `foo();` so from javascript

```
myApplet.foo();//it will call that method
```

Comment: @jigar - didnt worked :( its happening like when i am calling the same method with javascript its not working but when the same method is called by applet button then only its working... thats the reason i want applet button to be triggered

Comment: Are you sure you're not violating cross-site scripting rules? Is the codebase set correctly? Can you call any method in your applet from javascript successfully?